# Sound disappeared after changing PCM volume in Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

Today I've accidentally changed value of PCM channel at alsamixer and all sound has disappeared. There were no sound even after I removed the slider back to original position.

Here is screenshot of alsamixer and pavucontrol windows:

[image: screen]

I tried everything and spent all day in Google, but nothing helps. I'm using headphones connected to front audio jack.  Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not understand why there was a problem, but reinstallation of alsa worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```